# HAML - parameter with dash

Tags: html, haml

How can I convert this line

```
  <body data-spy="abcd">
```

to HAML syntax?

This one returns me an error

```
  %body{:data-spy => "abcd"}
```

Comment: It throws an error because of the hyphen. Just wrap the hyphenated string in quotes: `%body{:'data-spy' => "abcd"}`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

HAML Syntax for the HTML5 Data Field:

```
%div{ :data => {:id => '555'} }
```

Now, I started messing around, and it looks like this only works with "data" -- other tags need to be:

```
%div{ "star-datas" => "hello!" }
```

Your example:

```
%body{:data => { :spy => 'abcd'}}
```

Comment: Ran into a problem using this syntax, because I needed "data-0" and :0 isn't a valid symbol, so I changed my syntax to `:data => {'spy' => 'abcd'}`

Comment: Anything can be a symbol. If it's not valid by itself, just wrap it in quotes and prepend a colon:
`{ :'0' => 'this is a symbol', :'so-is-this' => true }`

Answer (score 17):

I don't know why I didn't post this in the first place. The "correct" way to write your tag, `<body data-spy="abcd">`, in HAML, is to skip the `{}` entirely and use `()`:

```
%body(data-spy="abcd")
```

If you're not evaluating the values of the attributes as Ruby, you shouldn't be using `{:key => value}` syntax at all. Stick to `(key="value")` for static HTML attributes.

---

Original answer:

HAML has a specific syntax for working with data attributes which [CrazyVipa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510130/229044) summarizes nicely.

For the sake of completeness, I'll point out that you can also use quoted symbol syntax, both here and anywhere else in Ruby that you want to use a hyphen in a symbol:

```
%body{ :"data-spy" => "abcd" }
```

In general, `:"text"` is equivalent to `"text".to_sym`, allowing your symbol to contain characters it normally couldn't due to parser limitations. The following are all valid symbols:

```
:"symbol with spaces"
:"symbol-with-hyphens"
:"symbol
with
newlines"
:"def my_func(); puts 'ok'; end"
```

Note that quoted symbols will *not* work with Ruby 1.9's new hash syntax:

```
{ :"key-1" => "value" } # works in 1.8/1.9
{ "key-1": "value" }  # syntax error
```

Comment: What would be the Ruby1.9+ new hash syntax way to write itß

Comment: @YoLudke `%div{ data: {id: '555'} }`

Comment: I mean for the example with key-1 -> 
`%div{ data: { :"key-1" => "value" }}`in Ruby 1.9+ new has syntax

Comment: @YoLudke  You can't use new syntax for that symbol. In any version of Ruby, you'd write `:"key-1" => "value"`

Comment: @YoLudke  See my updated answer though; if the value isn't Ruby to be evaluated, use `(data-key-1="value")` instead.

Answer (score 13):

#### For HAML ruby compiler:

```
%div{data: {some_hyphenated_id: 'value'}}
```

and HAML automatically converts underscores to hyphens so I get:

```
<div data-some-hyphenated-id="value"></div>
```

FYI: if you need empty attribute just use `true` instead of `'value'`

#### Example:

Haml:

```
%div{data: {topbar: true}}
%div{data: {image_carousel: true}}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-topbar></div>
<div data-image-carousel></div>
```

To be more specific this syntax is valid for **ruby haml gem** as well as grunt task **grunt-haml** with `language` set to `ruby` (requires mentioned ruby haml gem installed)

Comment: The `data-topbar` is what I was looking for. Thanks.